# View and table in same name is it possible

Tags: mysql, database, view

Is it possible to create a mysql view and table in same name

for example i have a table hs_hr_employee i want create a view as a same name

```
create VIEW hs_hr_employee AS SELECT * from hs_hr_employee;
```

I m getting following error

```
#1050 - Table 'hs_hr_employee' already exists
```

Any help Thankful

Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can't , give to view different name like

```
hs_hr_employee_view
```

from [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

> Within a database, base tables and views share the same namespace, so
>   a base table and a view cannot have the same name.

Comment: That means i cant create table and view in same name thats bad .. any way thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

As stated, you can't do it with views, but you **can** with temporary tables.

If you create a temporary table with the same name as an actual table, the temporary table will *shadow* (hide) the actual table. This means that you can't access the actual table **until** you have dropped the temporary table:

```
mysql> create table t select 1; # actual table t
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.58 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create temporary table t select*from t; # temp table t
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.53 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert t select 2; # t refers to the temp table
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select*from t; # temp table
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table t; # temp table
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> show tables like "t"; # verify that actual table still exists. show tables will not show temporary tables
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_test (t) |
+--------------------+
| t                  |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

mysql> select*from t; # now t refers to the actual table
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table t; # actual table
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql>
```

However, temporary tables are gone (even if you do not `drop` them) once your session is disconnected. You'll need to re-create them every time you connect.

Comment: Good answer if question was "Temporary table and table in same name is it possible". But this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you create it under a different schema.

for example

dbo.Customers

user.customers  (this could be a view)

You can call it by including the schema or if you call it from a user that is assigned the schema.

This is for MS SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Not only in mysql server but in any sqldialect, tables and views in the same schema can't be with the same name as it will lead to ambiguity when you fire a select query like from where to select the columns either from table or view.

Comment: It's a MySQL question.

Comment: You're answering a question that was asked nearly ten years ago.  You're also using terrible grammar (unclear single run-on sentence) and not adding any new information.

Comment: @Dennis Many StackOverflow contributors do not speak or write English as their native language.

Comment: I am well aware of that, @Jeff - my wife speaks very little English.  Doesn't change the facts.